# Windows 8.1 doesn't refresh network when it reconnected after interrupted

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I am using a laptop, connect to home wifi. Sometime the network is lost, cause limited icon in network. After the network resume, my laptop doesn't recognize it and still display the limited icon. I cannot connect to network there. But after "forget that network" and reconnect, the network work again. Is this an bug of Windows 8.1 or my hardware?

Comment: I suspect it to be a FIRWARE or DRIVERS bug, can you update your WIFI device ? [ma-config](http://www.ma-config.com/en) What is your Hardware ?

Comment: Dell Vostro 2420, like this: http://www.dell.com/in/business/p/vostro-2420/pd

Comment: The driver can be found on their website : [Communication drivers (the first one)](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=VDNDK&fileId=3287437297&osCode=WB64A&productCode=vostro-2420&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CM)